# How to setup ADB for TCP on Galaxy S3 with broken USB port

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, adb

I have a SGH-I747 phone that has a problem with the USB port (it will charge, but is never recognized so no ADB. Phone was actually sent to Samsung and they stated 'Beyond repair - gross electromechanical damage').

I would like to use the phone for development and was hoping to setup ADB to work over TCP. Seems like the only way to set this up is to either have a rooted phone or be able to set the phone into tcpip directly over USB.

I was hoping to find an apk that would root this model but there doesn't appear to be one.

Is there any other way to get adbd into TCP listening mode?